# Network setup tab is not shown under Tools

Tags: multisite, customization

I'm trying to create a multisite so I did the necessary steps:

1. Created a wildcard subdomain
2. Backed up of course files `wp-config.php` and `.htaccess`
3. Edited the config file with adding line `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);` before the line "*...Happy blogging..*"

And now I cannot continue executing the following steps since the Network setup is not appearing under tools.

Comment: I have this exact same problem, and would greatly appreciate an answer. I set up my domain with multisite enabled, so all the necessary lines are in place in all the proper files (I checked as well). The option is simply not there under tools. An internet search has revealed nothing, so I'm basically dead in the water until I get this resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try putting the line `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );` somewhere near the topic your wp-config.php file. Also make sure you don't have anything like // or anything like on the same line as it may comment out the define statement.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network "Step 2: Allow Multisite "

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was that the single quotes got messed up somehow when I copy and pasted that chunk of

> define(‘WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE’, true);

Took me a while to notice the single quotes around WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE were not the same as the ones in the rest of the config file. Deleted and added proper single quotes and refreshed my page in the web browser and then I had the Network Setup option.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing, you haven't done is disabling all plugins.

> Also deactivate all active plugins. You can reactivate them again after the network is created.

Source : https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network → Step-1

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same thing. My fix was to actually type out the

> define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

line -- instead of copying and pasting the line. Once I did this the *Tools>Network* option appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was your issue, but I'll chime in here and report what solved this issue for me:

This process was started and not finished in our instance.  I needed to go back to the aforementioned screen and copy the `.htaccess` content that was provided for my environment.  I tried commenting out the define's that we manually put in `wp-config.php`, already.  Once I did that, the Network tool option reappeared.

Hope that helps others.

Comment: Did what Erutan409 suggested; comment out / in define(‘WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE’, true) ; did the trick. Didn't have to touch .htaccess or mess with quotes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @AndrewR I had to replace quotes and spaces from what I copied from the Wordpress Website.  Maybe due to working on/in Windows and transferring to Linux.